# Django Form not rendering on HTML

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I'm a beginner in developing with django, I've been having a problem with a form I've made, I've been searching for similar problems but none of them could solve my problem.

No field of the form render in the HTML but the button renders fine

my form:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Aluno


class NovoAluno(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = Aluno
        nome = forms.CharField(min_length=15, max_length=100)
        direccion = forms.CharField(min_length=10, max_length=250)
        ciudad = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=50)
        provincia = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=50)
        comunidad = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=50)
        cp = forms.IntegerField()
        faixas = ['Blanco', 'Gris', 'Amarilla', 'Naranja', 'Verde', 'Azul', 'Roxa', 'Marrón', 'Preta']
        graduacion = forms.ChoiceField(choices=faixas)
        inicio = forms.DateInput()
        nacimento = forms.DateInput()
        lic = ['Basica', 'Completa']
        licencia = forms.ChoiceField(choices=lic)
        documento = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=9)
        email = forms.EmailField(min_length=10)
        profesor = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=100)
        centro = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=50)
```

my views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from .forms import NovoAluno
from .models import Aluno


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'academia/home.html', {})


def novo(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NovoAluno()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('aluno_detalhes', pk=form.pk)
    else:
        form = NovoAluno()
    return render(request, 'academia/cadastro.html', {'form': form})


def pesquisar(request):
    return render(request, 'academia/pesquisa.html', {})


def aluno_detalhe(request, pk):
    aluno = get_object_or_404(Aluno, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'academia/aluno.html', {'aluno': aluno})
```

my model:

```
from django.db import models


class Aluno(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    comunidad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cp = models.IntegerField()
    nacimento = models.DateField()
    inicio = models.DateField()
    documento = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    email = models.EmailField()
    profesor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    centro = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    graduacion = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    licencia = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

content block that the form goes

```
 {% block content %}
    <h1>Novo Aluno:</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit">Cadastrar!</button>
    </form>
 {% endblock %}
```

Well, thanks in advance, and I'm sorry if it's a dumb mistake, but I can't 
see where it is...

Comment: Please update whole forms.py code

Comment: forms.py updated

Comment: try @brandondavid 's answer,it's right

Comment: Don't add your solution to your question. Post an answer instead.

Comment: Oh sry, I'm a total noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up forms.Form and forms.ModelForm. Try changing to a model form like this:

```
from django import forms


class NovoAluno(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Aluno
        fields = '__all__'
```

or if you want only specific fields:

```
class NovoAluno(forms.ModelForm):

        class Meta:
            model = Aluno
            fields = [
            'nome',
            'direcction',
            'ciudad',
]
```

or using "forms.Form" **remove the class Meta and model** from what you already have and (fix the indent):

```
class NovoAluno(forms.Form):
    nome = forms.CharField(min_length=15, max_length=100)
    direccion = forms.CharField(min_length=10, max_length=250)
    ciudad = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=50)
    provincia = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=50)
    comunidad = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=50)
    cp = forms.IntegerField()
    faixas = ['Blanco', 'Gris', 'Amarilla', 'Naranja', 'Verde', 'Azul', 'Roxa',
              'Marrón', 'Preta']
    graduacion = forms.ChoiceField(choices=faixas)
    inicio = forms.DateInput()
    nacimento = forms.DateInput()
    lic = ['Basica', 'Completa']
    licencia = forms.ChoiceField(choices=lic)
    documento = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=9)
    email = forms.EmailField(min_length=10)
    profesor = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=100)
    centro = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=50)
```

**Edit**: Everything mentioned above is fine, except when defining choices, they should be a 2-tuple pairs. You can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ChoiceField.choices). That way you will not get the "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

```
Class NovoAluno(forms.Form):
    #code suppressed
    faixas = (('1', 'Blanco'), ('2', 'Gris'), ... 
          ..., ('9', 'Marrón'), ('10', 'Preta'))
    graduacion = forms.ChoiceField(choices=faixas)

    ...
    etc
```

Comment: Now I got something diferent, ValueError at /aluno/new
too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: nice! For future reference the "too many values error" was caused by the faixas field. Changing it to a tuple of tuples (that act as a key|value pair when the form renders) should solve that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!!

```
from django import forms
from .models import Aluno


class NovoAluno(forms.Form):
    model = Aluno
    nome = forms.CharField(min_length=15, max_length=100)
    direccion = forms.CharField(min_length=10, max_length=250)
    ciudad = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=50)
    provincia = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=50)
    comunidad = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=50)
    cp = forms.IntegerField()
    faixas = (
              ('Blanco', 'Blanco'),
              ('Gris', 'Gris'),
              ('Amarilla', 'Amarilla'),
              ('Naranja', 'Naranja'),
              ('Verde', 'Verde'),
              ('Azul', 'Azul'),
              ('Roxa', 'Roxa'),
              ('Marrón', 'Marrón'),
              ('Preta', 'Preta'),
              )
    graduacion = forms.ChoiceField(choices=faixas)
    inicio = forms.DateInput()
    nacimento = forms.DateInput()
    lic = (('Basica', 'Basica'),
           ('Completa', 'Completa'),
           )
    licencia = forms.ChoiceField(choices=lic)
    documento = forms.CharField(min_length=4, max_length=9)
    email = forms.EmailField(min_length=10)
    profesor = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=100)
    centro = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=50)
```

Erased the class Meta, and then realised that the lists for the forms.ChoiceField weren't in the right format, changed for tuples and everything works fine!

Thx to @brandondavid